# After acDialog form made not visible ms Access eventually throws error when exiting

Tags: ms-access

I've got a search results form in my Access client which uses the trick of being a form opened in acDialog mode.  If the user cancels the search the form closes itself, if the user selects one of the search items, the form writes the result into an unbound field and then makes itself not visible.

The calling code will suspend (because of the `acDialog` mode) until either of the two events described in the previous paragraph happen.  The calling code checks to see if the form is still loaded - when it knows a search item has been requested, so it retrieves the item from the form and then closes it.  If the form was already not loaded, we assume the cancel route was chosen.

the search results datasource is a select statement `"SELECT * FROM details ORDER BY ..."`

This trick has worked for a while in the code where "details" is a linked table to another Access database

I am porting to SQL Server, and the details table is now dynamically linked at startup to the correct SQL Server instance. Using the following connection string

```
ODBC;driver=SQL Server;SERVER=ROO\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Test_DB;UID=my_app;PWD=xxxx;
```

(Passwords etc changed to protect the innocent)

When Access exits the application (AND ONLY THEN) - if the path through the code has resulted in using the visible = false trick then it exits with an error message.  There is no error message if there is an application exit where the path has been through the search form but the form closed itself before returning.

The error message is:

```
Cannot access database because of Error [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source 
name not found and no default driver specified
```

and will now Exit.

I need to find out precisely why this is happening and stop it.

Comment: Is there any way that you can do the reverse and fill an unbound text box on the calling form?  Does it help to do that?  :)

Comment: Not easy - the calling routine is actually in a module - so I can provide a service to the application to do this search. The module doesn't normally have a form that could be used.  I could create one and load it hidden just to receive the result, but I would prefer to find out what is happening here and why its throwing the error.

Comment: I did find a way to do like you suggest - I don't need a whole form to get the return result - just a global variable will do.  Now my application exits without error - go figure

Comment: I eventually found the problem - it was a real bug in my code.  I had missnamed the form I was trying to close, so it never closed

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with a work around.  I created a global variable for the form result and then always closed the search result form itself.  The underlying routine that was trying to pick up the result just uses the global variable.

This proved that making a Dialog box invisible to retrieve results is not reliable - the problem disappeared as soon as I changed it.